# what is the hessian matrix of $f(W) = \sqrt{Tr(W A_0 W A_1)}$? Here, $W$, $A_0$ and $A_1$ are positive semidefinite matrices and hermitian

Tags: matrix, derivative, hessian

what is the hessian matrix of $f(W) = \sqrt{Tr(W A_0 W A_1)}$? Here, $W$, $A_0$ and $A_1$ are positive semidefinite matrices and hermitian.

For the time being, I obtain the derivative as 
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial W} = \frac{A_0^T W^T A_1^T + A_1^T W^T A_0^T}{2\sqrt{Tr(W A_0 W A_1)}}$. 
I want to know the next step.....

Comment: this would be a better fit for Math.SE

Comment: also, take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix_identities